# Optimal way to commit to DB via the Item Pipeline?

Tags: sqlalchemy, scrapy

All right, I'm using Scrapy & SQLAlchemy to scrape data and store it into a SQLite DB. Now, everything is working fine, but something bugs me and I can't find the answer.

So, in the process_item function inside Pipelines, what is the optimal way to commit to the DB. Most people seem to do something like this:

```
   def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """
        session = self.Session()
        #Do some stuff
        try:
            session.add(ItemClass)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

And I've also seen this:

```
   def close_spider(self, spider):
        # We commit and save all items to DB when spider finished scraping.
        try:
            self.session.commit()
        except:
            self.session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            self.session.close()
```

My main interrogation revolves around method 1. It seems inefficient to get the session every time, commit a single item to the DB, then close the session, for every single item. Now the second method bugs me too because it waits until the scraping process is over to commit to the DB, which could cause problems if the spider crashes and you lose everything scraped.

Is there an in between, could I commit every n items ? Or is this irrelevant since modern DB are so powerful they don't care about multiple commits in a short time. It's mostly about optimizing the commit process, I might be overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is the way to go. [Sessions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html) should not be that expensive.

Alternatively, do not use SQL Alchemy, or use only [SQL Alchemy Core](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html) instead of the ORM.